# How i can initialize a array with record items in pl/sql?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I'm relatively new to pl/sql and i'm trying to make a list with records objects but i dont know how to initialize for each item of the list both fields from record item. For example : in procedure "new item" how i can initialize example(1) ? with example(1).id_std := integer and example(1).procent := integer ? Thanks!

This is how my code looks like :

```
set serveroutput on;
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE newExercise IS
      TYPE item IS RECORD(
      id_std INTEGER,
      procent INTEGER
      ); 
     TYPE tabel IS VARRAY(5) OF item;
     PROCEDURE newItem (example tabel);
     example2 tabel := tabel();
end newExercise;
/
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY newExercise IS

    PROCEDURE newItem (example tabel) IS
    BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..example.LIMIT LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(example(i));
    end loop;
    end newItem;
end newExercise;
/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Record types are for storing the results of queries. So you could do this:

```
declare
    recs newExercise.tabel;
begin
    select level, level * 0.25
    bulk collect into recs
    from dual
    connect by level <= 5;

    newExercise.newItem (recs);
end;
/
```

Note that VARRAY is not a suitable collection type for this purpose, because it's not always possible to predict how many rows a query will return. It's better to use

```
TYPE tabel IS table OF item;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you refer to the record you usually have to specify specific fields. This populates the records with calculated values; to be able to do that I've had to changed the procedure argument from the default `IN` direction to `IN OUT`, both in the specification:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE newExercise IS
  TYPE item IS RECORD(
    id_std INTEGER,
    procent INTEGER
  ); 
  TYPE tabel IS VARRAY(5) OF item;
  PROCEDURE newItem (example IN OUT tabel);
                          -- ^^^^^^ make in/out to be updateable
  -- example2 tabel := tabel(); -- not used
END newExercise;
/
```

and in the body:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY newExercise IS
  PROCEDURE newItem (example IN OUT tabel) IS
                          -- ^^^^^^ make in/out to be updateable
  BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..example.LIMIT LOOP
      -- extend collection to create new record
      example.extend();
      -- assign values to record fields
      example(i).id_std := i;
      example(i).procent := 100 * (1/i);
    END LOOP;
  END newItem;
END newExercise;
/
```

The `LIMIT` is five, from the definition, but the varray instance is initially empty (from `tabel()`). For population you can loop from 1 to that limit of five, but you have to `extend()` the collection to actually create the record in that position. Records are created with all fields set to null by default. You can then assign values to the fields of each record. (I've just made something up, obviously).

You can then test that with an anonymous block:

```
declare
  example newExercise.tabel := newExercise.tabel();
begin
  -- call procedure
  newExercise.newItem(example);

  -- display contents for debuggibg
  FOR i IN 1..example.COUNT LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Item ' || i
      || ' id_std: ' || example(i).id_std
                               -- ^^^^^^^ refer to field
      || ' procent: ' || example(i).procent);
                                -- ^^^^^^^ refer to field
  END LOOP;
end;
/


Item 1 id_std: 1 procent: 100
Item 2 id_std: 2 procent: 50
Item 3 id_std: 3 procent: 33
Item 4 id_std: 4 procent: 25
Item 5 id_std: 5 procent: 20


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

I've put the original loop to display the contents of the array in that block, as you wouldn't generally have that as part of a procedure. You could still use `LIMIT` for that loop, but `COUNT` is safer in case the procedure doesn't fully populate it.

You can also extend once before the loop:

```
  PROCEDURE newItem (example IN OUT tabel) IS
  BEGIN
    -- extend collection to create all new records
    example.extend(example.LIMIT);
    FOR i IN 1..example.LIMIT LOOP
      example(i).id_std := i;
      example(i).procent := 100 * (1/i);
    END LOOP;
  END newItem;
```

If you already know the values you want to assign - and they aren't coming from a table, in which case you'd use APC's approach - you can just assign to the last created record; this is a rather contrived example:

```
  PROCEDURE newItem (example IN OUT tabel) IS
  BEGIN
    example.extend(); -- first record
    example(example.LAST).id_std := 1;
    example(example.LAST).procent := 7;
    example.extend(); -- second record, left with null fields
    example.extend(); -- third record
    example(example.LAST).id_std := 3;
    example(example.LAST).procent := 21;
    example.extend(); -- fourth record, left with null fields
  END newItem;
```

and the same anonymous block now gives:

```
Item 1 id_std: 1 procent: 7
Item 2 id_std:  procent: 
Item 3 id_std: 3 procent: 21
Item 4 id_std:  procent: 


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Notice the null values, and that there is no 5th row.

Or again extend the collection once, and refer to the numbered records directly:

```
  PROCEDURE newItem (example IN OUT tabel) IS
  BEGIN
    example.extend(4);
    example(1).id_std := 1;
    example(1).procent := 7;
    example(3).id_std := 3;
    example(3).procent := 21;
  END newItem;
```

which gets the same result from the anonymous block.